# Critique - Is this font too light and small to read?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, design-principles

[image]

This is 3.5x2 inches business card. The font size of contact details is 6.5 pt currently. Personally I feel it is a bit small (I tested it after printing on a normal A4 paper in its actual size). It looked small to me.

Also, the font is Helvetica Neue Light. I don't have any Regular or Normal font for this. So I used Light as it felt okay to me.

Most people (3 out of 4) in my office said it's okay. But doubt arised when I read a few answers on SE which suggested font should be 7, 8 or even 10 pts for better readability.

Given all that, is this font too light and small to read?

PS: Recently I've been banned twice from this SE. If this question violates some rule, kindly warn me here again, so I can improve, before you ban me again. There is no intention to break the rules of SE. I have read the guidelines and I feel it is according to them.

Comment: Why close and down votes?

Comment: "I think it's too small"... "Most people (3 out of 4) in my office said it's okay": so the close votes are because answers might lean on opinions to be answered. Although in this specific case I agree with Scott, font is too small - _in my opinion_.

Comment: Down votes = Primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: @Lucian @ Luciano I really can't understand this concept. I got printed 800 cards today, with 6.5 pt and as expected my boss didn't complain but she agreed that it could be better. And I didn't like it either. I was sure it would be small. If something looks ugly, then it is probably ugly. So how can it be opinion based? If 70 experienced people are saying it's not correct size, and 30 say correct,  I WON'T CALL IT OPINION BASED. If you call this opinion, almost every critique question can be questioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6.5pt type is **far too small** for **any** business card contact information. **ANY card**.

## Form vs function

It doesn't matter what font is used, 6.5pt type is simply too small to be read easily and the **primary** function of a business card is to *read* the contact information. For people over 40 it's a matter of  physiology. The eyes simply are *not* as good once you reach a certain age. So, unless you can *absolutely guarantee* that *everyone* needing to use the card for reference is under the age of 35 you need to increase the type size.

In my opinion, the *minimum* type size for any business card should be 9pt, better if it's 10-11pts.

Comment: Ha, I just told Vikas in the chat room that it *might* be large enough, but I forgot that I'm nearing 40 myself and have noticed how my eyesight is becoming more limited. I can only focus on things on 20 cm distance or more (which seems to be average for my age). I still think being limited to such a giant size as 11 pts. seems a bit much. I can still reader smaller text. Form must follow function, BUT you also need to make good looking designs to catch people's attention. To me it's a compromise.

Comment: The thing with a business card though is.. if I can't read the number/email... it's tossed and forgotten. Yes I agree that larger type sizes can create challenges for design.. but that does not make small tiny, type a viable option. :)

Comment: Years ago, I was cleaning for a very old lady and one day I brought in her paper. I asked if she was still able to read it and was very impressed when she told me "I'll just put it in my computer". She was referring to a giant magnifying glass she had on her desk. :-)

Comment: @Scott can you please show some samples where type is 10+ points?

Comment: How would that help in any way @Vikas ? I won't post my work here (cc license attribution) and any layout I've created most likely won't work with your specific information. I have created a buh-zillion (okay, a lot) of cards over a few decades of work. They *always* adhere to a strict "nothing smaller than 8pts" rule. And 8pts is merely reserved for when a client wants to throw in unnecessarily advertisement text on the card. But every card I've ever created has no contact information smaller than 9pts.

Comment: @Scott no. I didn't mean you share your work. I just wanted to know online resources where I could see such examples.

Comment: @Scott BTW, my document resolution is 300 DPI for 3.5x2 inches. same 6.5 would print same size of font if I had 72DPI resolution in same dimensions?

Comment: You are working in Illustrator which is vector based and should export a pdf for print. Never rasterize text for print! It's less crisp. Especially small sizes. So resolution doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Too small.

I would use at least 8pt type for business cards. Get rid of the QR code, those things are (arguably) useless, increase font size. Move the social media stuff on the back of the card and increase font size again.

Most times people just go looking for the phone number or the email address.

Comment: *Move the social media stuff on the back of the card* back side is front view. I don't want too many details on front.